# How to enable TypeScript to infer the exact shape of data objects in a generic HttpServiceMock using Typescript Generics and Interfaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I am currently working with TypeScript and I want to achieve something that I don't really know if it is possible (I trust it is).

I have this code as example:

```js
interface HttpServiceMockData<T> {
  status: number;
  data: T;
  url: string;
}

export function createHttpServiceMock<T>(data: HttpServiceMockData<T>[]) {
  return {
    get: async (url: string): Promise<{ data: T }> => {
      const res = data.find((d) => d.url === url);
      if (!res) {
        throw new Error(`No data found for url ${url}`);
      }
      return {
        data: res.data,
      };
    },
  };
}
```

```
const service = createHttpServiceMock([
  {
    url: '/users/1',
    data: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'test',
    },
    status: 200,
  },
  {
    url: 'test',
    data: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'test',
      lastname: 'test',
    },
    status: 200,
  },
]);

const res = service.get('test').then((res) => {
  res.data // I want typescript to know the exact type here ( inference power )
});
```

At the moment TypeScript knows what to return but it doesn't know what shape exactly the data object has and it gives me lastname as optional, which I don't want.
I want to pass the URL and TypeScript should understand what I want to get.

Any idea?

Comment: I could see TypeScript getting confused about which object named `data` you're talking about... name your variables with more creativity :)

Comment: `const service = createHttpServiceMock<{id:number, username:string, lastname:string}>([.........`

Comment: Another option, if you want to `infer` type from data, if you can at least create one correct item and store inside a `const`, and then use `typeof` to extract it's type.  You could even re-add this const to the array to keep things `dry`.

Comment: In fact I don't want to force the type, i want typescript to know the shape of data if i change the url, and i also want him to autocomplete the param of the get method with only those that are in the array of data !

Comment: Typescript has inferred the type, you only have lastname in one item, so it correctly typed lastname as optional.  I'm a little unclear on what problem your trying to solve now. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sort of thing is where Typescript really shines, but it requires a bit more direction on your part.

[Try in the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAkIQA4GVYBuIKAsgPZIDWAIghAgDwAqAfKgN7CqoDO9EAVx4AuVGAEBbAEawA3F1QATOglFN53ATAA2ovjHABzeQF9gwKAA9sZGBFRwBYJBBBkwqJDCh0omHPgwRKQUlAyBwVA8qFbQYIrR-niExFDkVLT0DAhgAJ4sLAAUCsr0ogBKPoru2rkAgjAwCLnhKSg8LMAAlBwK3oIwHpzc3IZQEKIIPLnOqMwIMGMQAKo6MZZxCagRqTwA2gDkWtoHALpFx2oLS6vaXQojI6IACjBkEiA8UAzsSiqihR27VQADIOKhjqgrotxrdUCYuodSggzvC2ABeNjDR6edx8VDeaLov70AB0cHAikKhUUPUxSlJkPRzIhOi6GhxIDgqEKAEJCT1sTjUBAABZvADuYigUoAoo1bIUAAYAOTIJIQDjITkUWpgrO0qAAJOxjiYleyHiMzML+lohlbHsjRITSciADSO+Ec7gmT2+0zmJB4+xfIKpVDErw+aBJIFpUKFPYKIUG0QHAD0QlgPAzAEYDtwpriwHx-SNnb1hSBFKI8+XHtnBggJFB09A+AcG-Du3w6EJRAAmAAMw-LfpTVsuqAOHYgXatldT3Brde7mjDYBbbZnc4Xwu0UwgW9b7ai8+7E8efcEIlQI7HChMqGLwdLEE9p0twDf+MJkd4NooFJJZClnc8Di6UkxSgMBqQFSMsT6KI3RUVAMwzVAAElUAlHJ7AgXJsCiLwQGwAj1UoMAyClGD1mQAiiLQUVYDQQpUHAOBWOcNAbAlWBUHubhXWRUlDz4E9gIkOgkFFUxv1-exCUHACw0iEDxjArMw1zAsoJguDCgQ+lsREtCMOw3D8JFJieFI8iRUo6jaJY+iXBs4jUBY7weQ4sAuO8HjUD4gShIJFDRPE49t1JaSIFk+T5GANTUg0iAwJrdxoEsT553uYALLqbRoGbVwCCgWpgEIzz4yYBApG0NBiV+PYAGk-N4CADDAQxTihDAsGScMQgyFRsjyNgzCsGw7AcJwXDcDxo18OMgPSSg6oa7542iWJYK2Wr6saooSn+bYgJ4boq3CgYHUeJZJmmWZ5hhFY1j2+JokoKBcjIbkdouHRoRuNkvW4F43g+L4fg1UQdr2OrXtuU4kRUVETAxJDhWE8Z7QheIoApMAoF1YsclyH0eyfQMfxDQDhqgFSo28FbBvjdbNsawpsUObSc3zVFRFTadMybXTC1Qbsly9VdUHrL0m0ks9O0vXt+AHe9R3Hcs5364Wgd3CCpbO5cONrOX1whTdt2Vi8vSipXDZVq0rxGG8NYfbXgARJLFPCngAGZVKAwc0rAvd9JYwzjKx-3UPodDMJwvDIA8kiDAciAnJokVXKsBi0681jfM47iUGCmjQuQnh44QMSj0k2KZLk72FLpwkABZg4Z0PQNFnSBcj2D4KiOlY7MhOLOT6zqvTsiKNQKic7o-P3NnoufPY0vAvLkL9TCie64dmK4oS1vZCAA).

```js
export function createHttpServiceMock<Services extends HttpServiceMockData<any>>(
  data: ReadonlyArray<Services>
) {
  return {
    get: async <TargetUrl extends Services['url']>(url: TargetUrl)
        : Promise<{ data: (Services & { url : TargetUrl })['data'] }> => {
      //...
    },
  };
};
```

In short, a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) type (`Services`) representing your services is formed from the array. The `url` argument in the returned `get` function is constrained to the `url` property of the services given. It's represented as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics) essentially so that it can be used as a type variable. For `get`'s return type, the correct service type is selected by [intersecting](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the `Services` union and an object type with the target `url` property. Then its corresponding data property is selected.

Also, when you call with your services, the `url` properties (or the service) must be declared with `as const` so that Typescript interprets the `url` tags [literally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), instead of as ordinary `string`s.

```js
const service = createHttpServiceMock([
  {
    url: '/users/1' as const,
    data: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'test',
    },
    status: 200,
  }, // or
  {
    url: 'test',
    data: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'test',
      lastname: 'test',
    },
    status: 200,
  } as const,
]);
```

Alternatively, if you define your services as a table, you can get rid of the whole union intersection business:

```js
type ServiceTable = { [K in string] : HttpServiceMockData<any> };
export function createHttpServiceMockTable<Services extends ServiceTable>(
  data: Services
) {
  return {
    get: async <TargetUrl extends keyof Services>(url: TargetUrl)
        : Promise<{ data: Services[TargetUrl]['data'] }> => {
      //...
    },
  };
};

const service2 = createHttpServiceMockTable({
  ['/users/1'] : {
    //...
  },
  test : {
    //...
  },
});
```

The [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) is the best resource for more background. The section on [Objects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) is especially relevant.

Comment: Reading your answer, helps me understand the question.  Nice answer, and understanding of the OP.  Def up vote from me. :)

Comment: Yeah !! You are a master !! 
It is almost what I'm trying to achieve, I wanna get rid of the table, but I understand it better now ! 

Thank you dude !